# Multiply a value with a specific value of an array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I have an `array`.First i want to search a specific value in that `array` and want to `return` that value with multiple by a value.I was trying below way but in this way its multiple with `array` `key`s but i want it will multiple with `array`s `value`. It can be very simple but i don't know the solution.

```
<?php 

$arr = ['10','20','30','40'];
$searching = array_search("30", $arr); 
if ($searching) {
    $result = $searching*30;
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

**Output is : 60**

**But i want : 900**

Comment: From the manual `array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful` **The Key** Not **The Value** If in doubt [there is always the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) ___as a last resort of course, we dont want to ware it out___

Comment: So you always want to multiply by the same value as you're searching for? I mean, if you know the value beforehand why multiply by the result? E.g. `if (in_array($query, $arr)) { echo $query * $query; }`

Comment: what is the benefit? It's enough to only find the occurrence of value in array.

Comment: @Yoshi No what if he was searching for 40 and wanted to still multiple by 30

Comment: @RiggsFolly Then it would be `{ echo 30 * $query; }`. I just don't understand why the actual search-result is relevant. All parameters are known, so the real question asked is *is my value in the list*.

Comment: @Yoshi Yup you have a valid point. And that is the answer he picked as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`in_array` function will help you to determine if value exists in your array.
If it exists - return this value, multiplied by some other value.

```
$arr = ['10','20','30','40'];
$search_val = 20;
if (in_array($search_val, $arr)) {
    echo 30 * $search_val;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> The array_search() function search an array for a value and returns
>   the key.

**Try this:**

`array_search` give you the index, so use `$arr[$searching]`.

```
$arr = ['10','20','30','40'];
$searching = array_search("30", $arr); 
if ($searching) {
    $result = $arr[$searching] * 30;
    echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
<?php 
$arr = ['10','20','30','40'];
$val = 20;
echo (in_array($val, $arr)) ? (30 * $val) : "";
?>
```